# Filtrar cronograma por fecha

Tags: php, postgresql

Necesito filtrar un cronograma por fechas, en este se registraran cursos durante todo el año pero necesito que muestre solo los del mes

```
$fecha_filtro = date('Y/m/d');

if ($fecha_filtro == '05'){
$pg = "select * from cronograma where fecha ilike '%".$fecha_filtro."%'";
$query = pg_query($pg);
}
```

El 05 del if es el mes que necesito que filtre, asi como lo tengo no sirve.

Comment: Lo tenia tipo varchar, pero lo cambie a date e igual no funciona

Comment: Si, que muestre los del mes que este corriendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Si el campo `fecha` es del tipo `date` y el formato de la fecha es el por defecto (`Y-m-d`)

Para filtrar solo los del mes en `curso` (*es decir, mes actual*), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$fechaDesde = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y')));
$fechaHasta = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') + 1, 1, date('Y')));

$pg = "select * from cronograma 
       where fecha >= '".$fechaDesde."'::DATE 
       and fecha < '".$fechaHasta."'::DATE";
$query = pg_query($pg);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias.